# Trying to print multiple text in same line with append method but outputs are different

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to print possible number combinations in single line as list but the list have wrong output. My output is like this:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

When it should be like this:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

My code is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 1
    y = 1
    z = 1 
kordinat = ["x","y","z"]
result = []
for xx in range(x+1):
    kordinat[0] = xx
    for yy in range(y+1):
        kordinat[1] = yy
        for zz in range(z+1):
            kordinat[2]= zz
            print(kordinat)
            result.append(kordinat)
print(result)
```

Comment: Are you trying to print elements of a list in a new line?

Comment: i want output in input(result) to be not only 1's but having different values like this: [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions: 1. How to output the list in multiple lines and 2) how to construct the list in the first place. You need to post two different questions for that.

Comment: @satyamsoni You should post that as an answer.

Comment: to print 1 sublist per line, you could use `print('\n'.join([str(r) for r in result]))` or more efficient simply `for r in result:
    print(r)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line:

```
result.append(kordinat)
```

to

```
result.append(kordinat.copy())
```

list is passed or assigned as reference so if you change the value it'll change everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

You should take [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

result = list(product(range(2), repeat=3))
print(result)
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

**EDIT:**
This does not explain, why you end up having a list full of `[1, 1, 1]` elements. The reason can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly). Through all your iterations, you work with a list called `koordinat`. When you append this to your overall list `result`, you append a reference to the very same object all the time. So you will have a list full of references to the same list `koordinat`. So changing `koordinat` to `[1, 1, 1]` in the last iteration, will change all references in your `result` list to this value as well. This can best be seen, when you print `result` after each `append()`

Comment: Thanks. This have made me understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To print elements of list in new line use `pprint` as below,

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(result)
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1]]
```

**Edit-1:**

Assuming, you are trying to find the binary numbers of the sequence. In your example, it is from `0-7`(1-byte or 8-bits).

Try this,

```
>>> result = [[int(j) for j in "{0:03b}".format(i)] for i in range(8)]
>>> pp(result)
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: ty for answering but i don't want the result to be all 1's. i want it to have different values like this: [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1].
But I can't understand why it only results 1's.

Comment: @LütfullahErkaya Have you read my answer? I gave explanation on why that happens and also provided a link where this behavioir is explained in detail. Also the answer of krishna points into this direction!

Comment: Yeah, i read it and now i see the problem. ty

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the possible combinations of 0,1 of size 3, use **combinations** from itertools and call it as **combinations([0,1],3)**. This will give you all the possible combinations you are expecting

Comment: `list(combinations([0,1], 3))` gives an empty array. I am not sure why, though.

Comment: Use this 
`
from itertools import product as p
print(list(p(range(2),repeat=3)))
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
`